# Is there an Info.plist key "Privacy - ... Usage Description" for screen recording in macOS?

Tags: macos, privacy

I can't find a plist key for Screen Recording to provide a custom usage explanation. Is this my own oversight in looking through docs?

Right now I can prompt and have the user enable permissions using the temporary-exception entitlement for screencapture.interactive.

Comment: How are you getting that prompt?

Answer (score 0):

Not really?

If you're using: `AVCaptureScreenInput`, then I'd suggest checking the user selected files as I think that cache gets involved here and might flag up.